# Shell script to check if the logs are generating for the current timestamp

Tags: linux, shell

The requirement is to check if the log files are generating for the current timestamp.

If Yes: Don't perform any action.
If No: Then check the java process(ABC.jar), kill the existing process and start the new process.

Below is the script which I have tried to execute and got the below error.

Kindly help me in fixing the issue and a better way to implement.

Script.

```
#!/bin/sh
NOTIFYJARFILE='ABC.jar'
cd /test/script
echo "Inside the directory"
ls -ltrh | tail -1
echo "Files are listed"
PERVIOUS_TIME = cat 'test.log' | date "+%D %T"
echo "PERVIOUS_TIME"
CURRENT_TIME = date "+%D %T"
echo "CURRENT_TIME"
if [ $CURRENT_TIME -eq $PERVIOUS_TIME ]
then
echo "Logs are generating for the currentTimestamp | `date`"
else
echo "Logs are Not generating for the currentTimestamp | `date`"
#Checking the running ABC Jar process
PID=ps ax | grep -v grep | grep ABC.jar | awk '{ print $1 }'
kill -9 $PID
#starting the Notify Jar process
echo "Starting the ABC jar | `date`"
java -jar /test/script/$NOTIFYJARFILE > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
```

Error:

```
Inside the directory
test.log
Files are listed
Notify.sh: line 7: test.log: command not found
07/30/19 14:10:04
PERVIOUS_TIME
Notify.sh: line 9: +%D %T: command not found
CURRENT_TIME
Inside If loop
Logs are generating for the current timestamp | Tue Jul 30 14:10:04 EAT 2019
```

Comment: Post your code on and fix all errors as indicated and suggested by https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

Just try this way at assigning variables, your variable should know that it is a command output, so:

```
PERVIOUS_TIME=$(cat 'test.log' | date "+%D %T")
```

and

```
CURRENT_TIME=$(date "+%D %T")
```

or this way:

```
PERVIOUS_TIME=`cat 'test.log' | date "+%D %T"`

CURRENT_TIME=`date "+%D %T"`
```

Comment: Also please take care about spaces at assigning variables, (A=$B, not A = $B)